# Cannot boot into ubuntu after repartitioning

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, grub-efi

Having successfully dual-booted my system, I decided to attempt to triple-boot Kali-Linux (legacy), Windows 8 (UEFI), and Ubuntu 13.10 (UEFI). I freed up some disk space (5 gb if I remember correctly) and installed Kali Linux. Amazingly, it worked like a charm, and GRUB enabled me to boot into both a UEFI and a legacy sistem from the same menu.

But then there was a problem. As I had partitioned such a small hard disk space (5gb) for Kali, naturally I filled up my Kali partition within a week. Disappointed in my stupid decision, I booted into windows and shrunk my Ubuntu partition by 25 gigs, then shifted my ubuntu partition and my swap partition to the right so that my Kali partition could be expanded( My partition setup can be seen in the following [image](http://i60.tinypic.com/25ez2hg.png)).

After expanding my Kali partition, I rebooted my system and could not boot into ubuntu (grub was still intact). In response, I created a boot-repair disk, and then reinstalled GRUB. Unfortunately, after rebooting my system again, my caps lock blinked and I was confronted with the following [error screen](http://i60.tinypic.com/21czehx.jpg).

Any help would be appreciated. I am also curious as too what caused this issue, as it did not affect (to my knowledge) grub (I could still boot into Kali Linux) or the contents of the partition with Ubuntu on it (I could still open and read my files).

Answer (score 0):

First, you wrote:

> GRUB enabled me to boot into both a UEFI and a legacy sistem from the same menu.

You're almost certainly mistaken, because GRUB does not support switching boot modes (BIOS to EFI or EFI to BIOS). You could probably boot your Kali from Ubuntu's EFI-mode GRUB or Ubuntu from Kali's BIOS/CSM/legacy-mode GRUB, but in those cases, the target OS will be running in the boot mode of the boot loader, rather than in the OS's original installation mode. Linux is flexible that way; the kernel and subsequent tools don't really care how they're loaded, and will adapt to the boot environment without further reconfiguration. (There are some exceptions having to do with the initialization of hardware, but that's a matter that doesn't seem to affect you....)

As to your boot problem, it looks like GRUB is misconfigured. Either you changed your GRUB configuration (knowingly or not) when repartitioning or the repartitioning has changed the identities of some of your partitions, which has thrown GRUB off. Either way, the [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair) utility might fix the problem; however, given your odd configuration with a (presumed) mixture of EFI-mode and BIOS-mode GRUB installations from two distributions, there's a chance that Boot Repair will become confused and do no good, or maybe even make matters worse. If you try Boot Repair and it doesn't work, post back with the URL that it gives you; that will provide us with more detailed information about your configuration, which should help in providing a fix.

Another option is to install my [rEFInd boot manager.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) You can do this while minimizing the risks by trying the USB flash drive or CD-R version (available from the [downloads page](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/getting.html)). If you can boot from it, it should present options for booting Windows, Ubuntu, and Kali (although the latter two may not be clearly differentiated in the menu). Trying this is risk-free because you're not modifying your disk or NVRAM options when booting via the rEFInd external medium. If you can get into all three OSes via rEFInd, then you can install the rEFInd Debian package from Ubuntu. This should make rEFInd your default boot manager. You can then clean up the boot menu and assign distinctive icons for both Ubuntu and Kali, as described [here.](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/configfile.html#hiding)